# Is there a better way to list the file and view the last edited file?

Tags: linux

Is there a better way to list the file and view the last edited file?
Eg: This is how I normally end up doing,  to view the last edited file 
    1.  ls -lrt
    2. Copy the last file name using mouse
    3. Vim (shift + insert) filename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
vim $( ls -t | head -n1 )
```

1. As an explanation, the `$( command )` returns the output of the command.
2. The command `ls -t | head -n1` lists files ordered by time, then pipes that to head, which returns the first file listed.
3. The vim command with a file name opens the file . . .

Obviously, if you really just want to view the view, substitute `cat`, `less`, `more` or similar for `vim`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 3. middle-click (you still hold the mouse you used to select the filename, right?), <kbd>Control-a</kbd>`vim`<kbd>space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: What's the ctrl-a for?  Select all in the terminal?

Comment: @ernie: go to the beginning of line

Comment: oh, that was a series of commands . . . paste using the mouse, ctrl-a, type vim, space, and then enter . . . if this were the case, I'd suggest just copy, type vim, space, paste, then enter . . . skip the ctrl-a . . .

Comment: @choroba I wanted to avoid using mouse ..thanks for ur time!